# Club together N consecutive line in shell?

Tags: text-processing

Let say I have a text file in this format

```
field1a
field2a
field3a
field1b
field2b
field3b
```

I want to club 3 (or in general case N) consecutive lines, how will I do it with `sed` or other command line utility in bash shell?

expected output

```
field1a:field2a:field3a
field1b:field2b:field3b
```

Answer (score 12):

```
 paste -sd '::\n' file
```

​​​​​​​
Where lines of `file` are `s`elf-`paste`d with themselves with `:`, `:`, and newline as `d`elimiters in turn, or:

```
 <file paste -d : - - -
```

Where we `paste` the lines of stdin, stdin and stdin with `:` as `d`elimiter, stdin being opened on `file`.

Or:

```
 awk '{ORS=NR%3?":":"\n";print}' < file
```

Where the `O`utput `R`ecord `S`eparator is newline or `:` depending on whether the `R`ecord (line) `N`umber is a multiple of 3 or not.

(note the behaviour will vary across those approaches if the number of records in the input is not a multiple of 3).

Comment: The number of colons in the `paste` command determines the number of clubbed together entries, that was not clear to me on first sight.

Comment: You shouldn't redirect the file into awk as it takes files as arguments anyway. This can also cause problems( although i cannot find the thread again it was something to do with how it is interpreted on OSX). Also it could be rewritten as `awk 'ORS=NR%3?":":RS' file` as this will always equate to true.

Comment: @Jidder, it's rather the other way round (file name passed to `awk`) that's a problem (like for files with `=` in their name).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It isn't(although i didn't know `=` in a filename would break it) reading it in via `<` made it read the line in oddly because of the newlines or something but i can't find the thread :( ( i REALLY wish you could search by newest on the site and after 10 results it didn't jump back like 3 months). Anyway it looks like both ways have downsides.

Comment: @Jidder, if `awk < file` is processed differently from `awk file`, then that'd be a bug in the particular `awk` implementation, or we're talking non-POSIX systems. While the `awk ... file==x` is a problem with any `awk` implementation (can be worked around with `awk ... ./file==x` though).

Comment: In the general case: `n=3; paste -sd $(printf ':%.0s' {1..n} file)n=3; paste -sd "$(printf ':%.0s' $(seq 2 $n))\n" file`.

Comment: Just saw your `awk` version, so I am deleting my answer. Note `awk 'ORS=NR%3?":":RS'` suffices, because `print` is the default action when an action is True.

Comment: @fedorqui. True, at the cost of legibility though. I also generally avoid using assignments as conditions, because then you need to be extra careful that the assigned value never resolves to false (see [KasiyA's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166407/22565) for instance (`$1=$1`) for a case where that's a problem).

Answer (score 2):

For output formatting you can use `printf`

```
IFS='
'       # split on sequences of newline characters
set -f # disable globbing
printf "%s:%s:%s\n" $(cat file)
```

(note that it skips empty lines).

Or `sed` (if you like)

```
sed '$!N;$!N;s/\n/:/g' file
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas If you expect the number of lines in the input is not a multiple or 3 and want the last line in `a:b\n` form you can use `sed '{N;s/\n/:/g};{N;s/\n/:/g}'`

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
sed '$!N;$!N;y/\n/:/'
```

​​​​​​​​Though I guess that is less general than *N lines* than it should be. If the number of lines you want will always be at the end of the field like that then:

```
sed '$q;N;/1.$/!s/\(..*\)\(\n\)/\2\1:/;//P;D
' <<\INPUT 
field1a
field1b
field2b
field1c
INPUT
```

#### OUTPUT

```
field1a
field1b:field2b
field1c
```

...which stacks lines following one that ends with `1` then any single character until it encounters another also ending with a `1` then something else.

It would work for any number of occurring fields, but you may want to do...

```
sed '.../[^0-9]1.$/!...'
```

... if you get into multiple-digits.

Answer (score 0):

If I have just a few hundred or fewer lines, or if the number of fields per group varies, then vi works pretty well for me.

In vi, if I want to join the current and following 2 lines (3 lines of text in all), then ...

```
    3J
```

At this point, my cursor is on the concatenated line, so I step down to the next one ...

```
    j
```

I do the same modification relative to the current line by using the dot ...

```
    .
```

And again ...

```
    j
    .
```

Oops! That last group had 4 lines, not 3. I undo the latest modification ...

```
    u
```

and do it again, right this time ...

```
    4J
```

Next! ...

```
    j
```

... And so forth.

Note, if you intend to do this for your 360-million-field database load, or if your consecutive fields are usually 3, with a few groups of 4 and a maybe a rare group of 5 or 6, then you will probably want to endure the arcane syntax of taking yourself out of the loop, conditioning your data by steps, and maybe writing a program to test it and alert you for errors.

But if it's a small one-time job, then I just bear a few minutes of tedium and use vi.