# merge blocks of four line into one line

Tags: awk, sed

I am stuck on this.

i have an input file that looks like

```
16:20:03 Buy
DRIP
AMEX
500 13,51 USD
16:05:10 Sell
SQ
NYSE
100 36,32 USD
15:48:52 Sell
NXTD
Nasdaq
500 4,99 USD
15:48:52 Sell
NXTD
Nasdaq
500 4,99 USD
15:46:07 Buy
SOXL
AMEX
50 147,7209 USD
15:40:20 Buy
TEUM
AMEX
1 700 1,36 USD
15:40:19 Buy
TEUM
AMEX
300 1,36 USD
```

my goal is to get each four-line record onto one line, e.g.

```
16:20:03 Buy DRIP AMEX 500 13,51 USD
16:05:10 Sell SQ NYSE 100 36,32 USD
```

I know that each record is four lines. i also know that each record starts with (is separated by) a time on format hh:mm:ss

I have tried various awk commands specifying RS/FS OFS/ORS
I have tried different variants of sed like

```
sed 'N;N;s/\n/ /'
```

The awk prints first record only.
The sed doesn't manage to get all elements on same line

I can post more specific examples of what i have tried. It looks reallly simply. anyone who can give me a hint?

If you know an easier solution in another language, feel free to elaborate

Comment: or [Club together N consecutive line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/166370/22142) etc... plenty of similar questions...

Comment: Thanks for all the great answers, it looks like my problem was related to DOS Line breaks in the file. sorry for the post.

Answer (score 13):

#### Using paste

```bash
    $ paste -d' ' - - - - <file
    16:20:03 Buy DRIP AMEX 500 13,51 USD
    16:05:10 Sell SQ NYSE 100 36,32 USD
    15:48:52 Sell NXTD Nasdaq 500 4,99 USD
    15:48:52 Sell NXTD Nasdaq 500 4,99 USD
    15:46:07 Buy SOXL AMEX 50 147,7209 USD
    15:40:20 Buy TEUM AMEX 1 700 1,36 USD
    15:40:19 Buy TEUM AMEX 300 1,36 USD
```

#### Using sed

```bash
    $ sed 'N;N;N; s/\n/ /g' file
    16:20:03 Buy DRIP AMEX 500 13,51 USD
    16:05:10 Sell SQ NYSE 100 36,32 USD
    15:48:52 Sell NXTD Nasdaq 500 4,99 USD
    15:48:52 Sell NXTD Nasdaq 500 4,99 USD
    15:46:07 Buy SOXL AMEX 50 147,7209 USD
    15:40:20 Buy TEUM AMEX 1 700 1,36 USD
    15:40:19 Buy TEUM AMEX 300 1,36 USD
```

#### Using awk

```bash
    $ awk '{line=line " " $0} NR%4==0{print substr(line,2); line=""}' file
    16:20:03 Buy DRIP AMEX 500 13,51 USD
    16:05:10 Sell SQ NYSE 100 36,32 USD
    15:48:52 Sell NXTD Nasdaq 500 4,99 USD
    15:48:52 Sell NXTD Nasdaq 500 4,99 USD
    15:46:07 Buy SOXL AMEX 50 147,7209 USD
    15:40:20 Buy TEUM AMEX 1 700 1,36 USD
    15:40:19 Buy TEUM AMEX 300 1,36 USD
```

Answer (score 4):

Perl solution

```
perl -pe 's/\n/ / if $. % 4' < file
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line, processes it and prints it back to the 
  output;
- `$.` contains the input line number
- `s/\n/ /` replaces a newline by a space
- `%` is the modulo operator, so the condition reads "if the line number isn't divisible by four"

Answer (score 2):

**The easiest solution is probably with `ex`**, the non-visual form of `vi` (which is [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html)).

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/^/j4' x | ex input.txt
```

Equivalently:

```
printf 'g/^/j4\nx\n' | ex input.txt
```

---

Explanation:

The `printf` command just produces the following output, which are commands to `ex`:

```
g/^/j4
x
```

The `x` command means to save and exit.  Replace with `%p` if you want to print the modified file to standard output and *not* save changes (good for testing).

`g` is the global command and takes a regex (in this case `/^/` which will of course match on every line) and then a command.  The command is run on every line matched by the regex.

`j4` means to join the current line with the following three lines.  Spaces are put in between when joining.

---

You can also fire up `vi` and just type `4J` and then `j` to go down a line and then type `.`, and then `j` to go down a line and then `.`, etc.  But with the `ex` form any left-over lines at the end of the file (less than four) will be joined together; with the `J` command in `vi` this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{printf $0 (NR%4?" ":"\n")}' file1
16:20:03 Buy DRIP AMEX 500 13,51 USD
16:05:10 Sell SQ NYSE 100 36,32 USD
15:48:52 Sell NXTD Nasdaq 500 4,99 USD
15:48:52 Sell NXTD Nasdaq 500 4,99 USD
15:46:07 Buy SOXL AMEX 50 147,7209 USD
15:40:20 Buy TEUM AMEX 1 700 1,36 USD
15:40:19 Buy TEUM AMEX 300 1,36 USD
```